Mex complier issue (windows 10, cuda 10.1, visual studio 2017)
I am trying to follow this github and to open the code I am running into errors with the mex compiler:
% Apply pre-compilation modifier function to adjust the flags and
% parameters. This can be used to add additional files to compile on the
% fly.
if ~isempty(opts.preCompileFn)
  [opts, mex_src, lib_src, flags] = opts.preCompileFn(opts, mex_src, lib_src, flags) ;
end

% Compile intermediate object files
srcs = horzcat(lib_src,mex_src) ;
for i = 1:numel(horzcat(lib_src, mex_src))
  [~,~,ext] = fileparts(srcs{i}) ; ext(1) = [] ;
  objfile = toobj(flags.bld_dir,srcs{i});
  if strcmp(ext,'cu')
    if strcmp(opts.cudaMethod,'nvcc')
      nvcc_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
    else
      mexcuda_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
    end
  else
    mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
  end
  assert(exist(objfile, 'file') ~= 0, 'Compilation of %s failed.', objfile);
end

% Link MEX files
for i = 1:numel(mex_src)
  objs = toobj(flags.bld_dir, [mex_src(i), lib_src]) ;
  mex_link(opts, objs, flags.mex_dir, flags) ;
end

% Reset path adding the mex subdirectory just created
vl_setupnn() ;

if strcmp(arch, 'win64') && opts.enableCudnn
  if opts.verbose(), fprintf('Copying CuDNN dll to mex folder.\n'); end
  copyfile(fullfile(opts.cudnnRoot, 'bin', '*.dll'), flags.mex_dir);
end

% Save the last compile flags to the build dir
if isempty(opts.preCompileFn)
  save(fullfile(flags.bld_dir, 'last_compile_opts.mat'), '-struct', 'opts');
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                    Utility functions
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function check_compability(arch)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C++');
if isempty(cc)
  error(['Mex is not configured.'...
    'Run "mex -setup" to configure your compiler. See ',...
    'http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers ', ...
    'for supported compilers for your platform.']);
end

switch arch
  case 'win64'
    clversion = str2double(cc.Version);
    if clversion < 14
      error('Unsupported VS C++ compiler, ver >=14.0 required (VS 2015).');
    end
  case 'maci64'
  case 'glnxa64'
  otherwise, error('Unsupported architecture ''%s''.', arch) ;
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function done = check_deps(opts, tgt, src)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
done = false ;
if ~iscell(src), src = {src} ; end
if ~opts.continue, return ; end
if ~exist(tgt,'file'), return ; end
ttime = dir(tgt) ; ttime = ttime.datenum ;
for i=1:numel(src)
  stime = dir(src{i}) ; stime = stime.datenum ;
  if stime > ttime, return ; end
end
fprintf('%s: ''%s'' already there, skipping.\n', mfilename, tgt) ;
done = true ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function objs = toobj(bld_dir, srcs)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
str = [filesep, 'src', filesep]; % NASTY. Do with regexp?
multiple = iscell(srcs) ;
if ~multiple, srcs = {srcs} ; end
objs = cell(1, numel(srcs));
for t = 1:numel(srcs)
  i = strfind(srcs{t},str);
  i = i(end); % last occurence of '/src/'
  objs{t} = fullfile(bld_dir, srcs{t}(i+numel(str):end)) ;
end
if ~multiple, objs = objs{1} ; end
objs = regexprep(objs,'.cpp$',['.' objext]) ;
objs = regexprep(objs,'.cu$',['.' objext]) ;
objs = regexprep(objs,'.c$',['.' objext]) ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function mex_compile(opts, src, tgt, flags)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
if check_deps(opts, tgt, src), return ; end
args = horzcat({'-c', '-outdir', fileparts(tgt), src}, ...
  flags.base, flags.mex, ...
  {['CXXFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.cxx)]}, ...
  {['CXXOPTIMFLAGS=$CXXOPTIMFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.cxxoptim)]}) ;
opts.verbose && fprintf('%s: MEX CC: %s\n', mfilename, strjoin(args)) ;
mex(args{:}) ;

specifically this error in this block of code:
Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 599)
mex(args{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 508)
    mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;

How do I resolve this issue?
We tried to use 'nvcc' and switched over to 'mex'. We haven't been able to figure it out for months. We also installed matlab compiler MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler.
Here is more of the error message: and that works here is more of the error message:
`:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\src\bits\impl\imread_gdiplus.cpp:14:
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hadd_epi16(__m128i, __m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:42:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddw128' was not declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phaddw128 ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hadd_epi32(__m128i, __m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:48:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddd128' was not declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phaddd128 ((__v4si)__X, (__v4si)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hadds_epi16(__m128i, __m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:54:71:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddsw128' was not declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phaddsw128 ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                       ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hadd_pi16(__m64, __m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:60:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddw' was not declared in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phaddw ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);`
                                                             ^


Its impossible to say whats going wrong, wihtout showing the full error message. Did you successfully configre mex to compile C++ with mex -setup c++, and checked that you can compile one of the example files listed here? if you need to use GPU acceleration, stick to visual studio compiler and dont use MinGW.

@rinkert I did successfully configre mex to compile and i tried compile one of the example files and that worked, I edited it the post to show more of the error message

Seems MinGW is not supported for matconvnet. Try to setup c++ compilation with msvc. See this github issue
